# React-native navigation : this.props.navigation.navigate returns undefined is not an object

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, undefined, react-props

I don't get why this code returns **"Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')"**  I understand the problem is the redirection but with the constructor and the props it seemed to me that it was well written, can anyone give me tips, and advice or any help ?

Thanks a lot. In every other screen, the navigation works... This is my App.js :

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isFirstConnection: true,
      status: 0,
      fontLoaded: false
    };
  }

  async UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    let lang = await retrieveAppLang();
    let isConnected = await userSessionActive();

    if (lang.length == 2) {
      i18n.changeLanguage(lang);
    }

    if (isConnected === true) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("TabBar");
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      FunctionLH: require("./assets/fonts/FunctionLH-Light.ttf"),
    });

    const data = await this.performTimeConsumingTask();
    if (data !== null) {
      this.setState({
        isFirstConnection: false,
        status: 1,
        fontLoaded: true,
      });
    }
  }

  performTimeConsumingTask = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("result");
      }, 1500)
    );
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.status == 1) {
      if (this.state.isFirstConnection && this.state.fontLoaded) {
        return <SplashScreen />;
      } else {
        return <Navigation screenProps={'Authentication'} />;
      }
    }

    return (
      <ImageBackground
        source={require("./assets/images/background.jpg")}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
      >
        <View style={[styles2.container, styles2.containerCentered]}>
          <StatusBar hidden={true} />
          <View style={styles2.subContainer}>
            <Image
              style={styles2.logo}
              source={require("./assets/images/logo.png")}
            />
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#43300E" />
            <Text>{i18n.t("app.loading") + "..."}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}
```

My navigation file :

```
function getActiveRouteName(navigationState) {
  if (!navigationState) return null;
  const route = navigationState.routes[navigationState.index];
  // Parse the nested navigators
  if (route.routes) return getActiveRouteName(route);
  return route.routeName;
}

const SlidesStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Slides: {
      screen: Slides,
      navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
    SubscriptionSlides: {
      screen: SubscriptionSlides,
      navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
    Signup: {
      screen: Signup,
      navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
    Authentication: {
      screen: Authentication,
      navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
    Login: {
      screen: Login,
      navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
    Account: {
      screen: Account,
      navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
    Picture: {
      screen: Picture,
      navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
    MyTrips: {
      screen: MyTrips,
      navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
    About: {
      screen: About,
      navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
    Settings: {
      screen: Settings,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: `Settings`,
        headerStyle: { opacity: 0.7, height: 20, textAlign: "center" },
        headerTitleStyle: { color: "#6C6363", textAlign: "center" },
        headerTintColor: "#6C6363",
      }),
    },
    Category: {
      screen: Category,
      navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
    Contact: {
      screen: Contact,
      navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
    Faq: {
      screen: Faq,
      navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
    Stats: {
      screen: Stats,
      navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
    Subscription: {
      screen: Subscription,
      navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
    TabBar: {
      screen: TabBar,
      navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
    Rating: {
      screen: Rating,
      navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
    TripsForm: {
      screen: TripsForm,
      navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
    PayForm: {
      screen: PayForm,
      navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
    Terms: {
      screen: Terms,
      navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
    Ranking: {
      screen: Ranking,
      navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
    DateTimePicker: {
      screen: DateTimePicker,
      navigationOptions: { header: null },
    }
  },
  {
    mode: "modal",
    //headerMode: "float",
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      gesturesEnabled: false,
    },
    transitionConfig: () => ({
      transitionSpec: {
        duration: 350,
        easing: Easing.out(Easing.poly(4)),
        timing: Animated.timing,
        useNativeDriver: true
      },
      screenInterpolator: (sceneProps) => {
        const { layout, position, scene } = sceneProps;
        const { index } = scene;

        const height = layout.initHeight;
        const translateY = position.interpolate({
          inputRange: [index - 1, index, index + 1],
          outputRange: [height, 0, 0],
        });

        const opacity = position.interpolate({
          inputRange: [index - 1, index - 0.99, index],
          outputRange: [0, 1, 1],
        });
        return;
      },
    }),
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(SlidesStackNavigator);
```

Comment: Is this your app.js ? can you share how the intialize the stack ?

Comment: Have you added react-navigation ?

Comment: Yes this is my App.js 
React-navigation is in my navigation component. 
Do you want me to add it in my message ?

Comment: Modifying this way : ** if (isConnected === true && this.props && this.props.navigation) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("TabBar");   makes the error disappear.... it's weird but it's ok...

Comment: @Kimako from what i see, you are trying to access navigation outside the navigation container, better check this out https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/navigating-without-navigation-prop/